# Armory Ubuntu/Debian 0.96.0 signed with a different key than listed on the website

Tags: armory

I downloaded the Armory version for Ubuntu/Debian from here:
https://www.bitcoinarmory.com/download/

Under the "Offline Signing Key" section it lists the public key for verification to be: 98832223.   This key is also used throughout their verification instructions.  They also show the fingerprint for this key on that page.

However, the files I downloaded are signed with key 4922589A.  I looked that key up on pgp.mit.edu and it shows the key owned by "goatpig (Offline signing key for Armory releases)"  Now, I see that goatpig is the name of one of the contributors on github, but really anyone can make a key with that name and since the website doesn't reference the key, or give me a fingerprint for the key, that I can find, I am hesitant to trust it.

My question here really is, can anyone confirm what the proper public key is to verify the armory downloads.  Did I miss something?

--update

I see there are two armory websites  www.bitcoinarmory.com and btcarmory.com.  each has a 0.96.0 download and the hash of both installs are the same, so I assume they are the same file, they are also both signed with the same public key.  The difference is that bitcoinarmory.com says to verify with 98832223 and btcarmory says to verify with 4922589A.  Very confusing, but my best guess is that  4922589A is actually the proper key to verify the signature with.  Either way, I think I'm just going to stick with bitcoin-qt unless someone can help clear this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://bitcoinarmory.com is no longer Armory's official website. The official website is actually https://btcarmory.com. bitcoinarmory.com still hosts the new binaries, but they are only a mirror and everything else on the site is outdated.

Since Armory's development changed a few years ago, the actual release signing key is 4922589A as that is the new maintainer's signing key. This key is used on Armory 0.94.0 and above. The old signing key, 98832223, is the old maintainer's signing key.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/69czq6/does_anyone_still_use_bitcoin_armory_im_concerned/) and the comment below, the old Armory developers could no longer work on Armory and the project is maintained by a former employee.

https://www.bitcoinarmory.com/ is the website of the old project, is abandoned, but still has higher Google rank.

https://btcarmory.com/ is the website of the new project.

See Andrew Chow's answer for info about the keys.

Comment: There were no disagreements, just that ATI no longer had the ability to work on Armory and went out of business. One of their former employees began maintaining it and the change to the new maintainer (and new repo, etc.) was amicable and endorsed by Alan Reiner, the former maintianer.

Comment: OK, thanks, seems like I misunderstood, will edit the answer